# django-nvd3 remove the graph attributes Grouped,Stacked

Tags: django, django-templates

I displayed multiBarHorizontalChart in Django but it includes 2 radio buttons that is Grouped and Stacked Serie1,So i want to remove it....anyone give me the proper solution.

views.py

```
def demo_multibarhorizontalchart(request):

    nb_element = 10
    xdata = range(nb_element)
    ydata = [i + random.randint(-10, 10) for i in range(nb_element)]
    ydata2 = map(lambda x: x * 2, ydata)
   extra_serie = {"tooltip": {"y_start": "", "y_end": " mins"}}
   chartdata = {
   ’x’: xdata,
     ’name1’: ’series 1’, ’y1’: ydata, ’extra1’: extra_serie,
  ’name2’: ’series 2’, ’y2’: ydata2, ’extra2’: extra_serie,
  }
  charttype = "multiBarHorizontalChart"
 data = {
 ’charttype’: charttype,
 ’chartdata’: chartdata
 }
return render_to_response(’multibarhorizontalchart.html’, data)
```

Comment: Code please. stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There aren't any option to turn it off builded in django-ndv3. Your two options to this are:

1. Fork django-ndv3 with your solution (hard version)
2. - Set .nv-controlsWrap to display:none; in your css (this will disable Grouped, Stacked)
   - Set .nv-legendWrap to display:none; in css (this will disable Series1 etc.)

I'm currently working with django-ndv3 too, so maybe I will later need to do something more with it.

Comment: It works fine but i take two graphs ie.Pie chart and multihorizontalbar chart,so it works for both i wants for only multihorizontalbar chart.so what can i do for that

Comment: You can wrap charts in some divs and then do display:none; for only one of charts, like this:

`<div class='multibar-chart'>{% include_container "multibarchart_container" 400 600 %}</div>`

and in css:

`.multibar-chart .nv-controlsWrap { display:none; }`